# Case - when in two layers

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I'm trying to do an operation on a polygon layer to ask a different layer and if a condition is met then do an operation. It would be something like that:

```sql
Case
when ("DAP-OSM-BuildingsH-0m",'BuildCat') =1
THEN intersecting_geom_count('DAP-OSM-BuildingsH-0mClass1')
```

- where `DAP-OSM-BuildingsH-0m` is the other layer.
- `"BuildCat"` is a column in the layer `DAP-OSM-BuildingsH-0m`
- and the condition is `If` in the layer:

  - `DAP-OSM-BuildingsH-0m` and the value of the column `"BuildCat" = 1` then the operation is:
    `intersecting_geom_count('DAP-OSM-BuildingsH-0mClass1')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [refFunctions plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) you already have (`intersecting_geom_count`), you can write the following code :

```sql
CASE
  WHEN geomintersects('DAP-OSM-BuildingsH-0m', 'BuildCat') = 1
  THEN  intersecting_geom_count('DAP-OSM-BuildingsH-0mClass1')
END
```

Description of the `geomintersects` function from the doc:

> Retrieve target field value when source feature intersects target
>   feature in target layer
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `geomintersects(targetLayer,targetField)`
>
> **Arguments**
>
> `targetLayer` → the name of a currently loaded layer, for example 'myLayer'.
>
> `targetField` → a field in target layer we want as result when source feature is
>   within target feature, for example 'myField'.
>
> If targetField is equal to `'$geometry'`, the WKT geometry of `targetFeature` will be retrieved.
>
> Number of feature tested is limited to 100 000 to avoid time wasting loops.